# Move objects in a grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make these boxes move freely in the grid, but still respect these simple rules:

1. A box should only be able to move in one direction at a time.
2. Boxes can't overlap or break out the grid.

Right now they jump from cell to cell, now do I make them move freely? If moved one point by touch on X-axis then the box should also move only one point - not just animate to next grid.

Then on touchesEnded / touchesCanceled I could snap the box to the closest grid.

Thanks.

[image: Grid with boxes]

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (![self canMove])
        return;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    CGPoint cell = [self.grid getCellFromLocation:location];
    BOOL allowMove = [self canMoveTo:cell.x y:cell.y];

    if (allowMove) {
        CGRect rect = [self.grid getCellRect:self.grid.gridView x:cell.x y:cell.y];

        [self moved:cell.x y:cell.y];
        self.frame = rect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you're using now.

Comment: Show the code where you handle the touch events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, this makes the box move in one direction at a time, and then allows it to change direction when inside grid cell.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(self.center.x + location.x - self.lastLocation.x, self.center.y + location.y - self.lastLocation.y);
    CGPoint closestCenter = [self closestCenter:offset]; // Finds the closest grid cell center
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(offset.x - (self.size.width / 2), offset.y - (self.size.height / 2), self.size.width, self.size.height);

    if (fabsf(closestCenter.x - offset.x) < fabsf(closestCenter.y - offset.y)) {
        offset.x = closestCenter.x;
    }
    else {
        offset.y = closestCenter.y;
    }

    if ([self collisionLeftRight:rect]) { // Check collision against left/right side
        offset.x = self.center.x;
    }

    if ([self collisionTopBottom:rect]) { // Check collision against top/bottom side
        offset.y = self.center.y;
    }

    self.lastLocation = location;
    self.center = offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not the best to achieve that kind of nice animations, but that could be a possible solution for you, however it looks a bit ugly to me, but that little extension will provide you an idea which you can finalise later anytime.

so.

---

add this to the **Box.h** file:

```
@interface Box : UIView {
    BOOL _isAnimationInProgress;
}
```

instead of this line:

```
@interface Box : UIView
```

---

and override the **Box.m** with those changes:

```
- (id)initWithType:(NSInteger)type x:(NSInteger)x y:(NSInteger)y grid:(Grid*)grid {
    _isAnimationInProgress = FALSE;

    // (...)

}
```

and the following `-touches...` methods should look like these:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (![self canMove])
        return;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    CGPoint cell = [self.grid getCellFromLocation:location];
    BOOL allowMove = [self canMoveTo:cell.x y:cell.y];

    if (allowMove && _isAnimationInProgress == FALSE) {
        _isAnimationInProgress = TRUE;

        didMove = YES;
        CGRect rect = [self.grid getCellRect:self.grid.gridView x:cell.x y:cell.y];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location)) {
                [self moved:cell.x y:cell.y];
                self.frame = rect;
            }
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            _isAnimationInProgress = FALSE;
        }];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    _isAnimationInProgress = FALSE;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    _isAnimationInProgress = FALSE;
}
```

---

*NB: that was the best I could do with your structure of code.*

Comment: Okay, I see what your doing. What I rely wanted was to have totally free movement, so if I move the touch one point on X-axis the box should also move one point.

Comment: I see what your doing. What I really wanted: If moved one point by touch on X-axis then the box should also move only one point - not just animate to next grid.

Then on touchesEnded / touchesCanceled I could snap the box to the closest grid.

Comment: @Martin, for achieving this, you need to rewrite the structure of your code and your need to create a totally new concept. that is the  best what can be doable with this code without massive modification of the structure. your wish requires different concept certainly.

Comment: any hints? what would be the best way to do it? I've been rewriting this code many times, so starting from scratch again is no problem.

Comment: you should develop a concept for desired visual effect. there is no omnipotent hint here, you need to use your imagination, experience and knowledge; without them you won't be able to develop any visual effects.